# Slide out division zooming

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, styling

```
    $(function () {
    $("#clickme").click(function () {
        if($(this).parent().hasClass("popped")){
        $(this).parent().animate({right:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500}).removeClass("popped");
    }else {
        $(this).parent().animate({right: "0px" }, {queue: false, duration: 500}).addClass("popped");}
    });


    $(document).on('click',function(e){
        if($('#slideout').hasClass("popped")){
        $('#slideout').animate({right:'-280px'},{queue:false,duration: 500}).removeClass("popped");
        }
    });

    $('#slideout').on('click',function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

});

<div id="slideout">
    <div id="slidecontent">
        Yar, there be dragonns herre!
    </div>
    <div id="clickme">
    </div>
</div>
```

Its for slide out a div. But when i use this scripts, on zooming the website- the horizontal scroller not displayed. How can it solve?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:-

```
 $(document).on('click',function(e){
        if($('#slideout').hasClass("popped")){
        $('#slideout').animate({right:'-280px'},{queue:false,duration: 500}).removeClass("popped");
        }
    });
```

[**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/938/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){ /* Hide on Outside Click*/
    if($('#slideout').hasClass("popped")){
        $('#slideout').animate({right:'-280px'},{queue:false,duration: 500}).removeClass("popped");
    }
});

$('#slideout').on('click',function(e){ /*Ignore 'Hide on Outside Click' on clicking #slideout element*/ 
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This code should work

Your final code will be :

```
$(function () {
    $("#clickme").click(function () {
        if($(this).parent().hasClass("popped")){
        $(this).parent().animate({right:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500}).removeClass("popped");
    }else {
        $(this).parent().animate({right: "0px" }, {queue: false, duration: 500}).addClass("popped");}
    });


    $(document).on('click',function(e){
        if($('#slideout').hasClass("popped")){
        $('#slideout').animate({right:'-280px'},{queue:false,duration: 500}).removeClass("popped");
        }
    });

    $('#slideout').on('click',function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

});
```

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/939/)**

Comment: I added it like this. but the div not slide out on outer click.

Comment: It is working fine here :http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/939/  . I am testing it on Firefox v22.0 and you?

Comment: Works fine on chrome (up to date)

Comment: Which version of jquery neded for this? I am using this
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Aneesh I think 1.7 or higher but not sure. Anyway I have tested it on v1.9.1 . But I am sure that it works well on latest jquery version.

Comment: Can u post the link.?

Comment: it works fine now. But on zooming the web page, the horizontal scroller not showed.